# Few words missing in the automated pdf export from jasperserver report

Tags: pdf-generation, etl, talend, jasperserver

I need to schedule report exporting for a particular department which needs to run daily. And each day the list of employees for that department changes.

So i am using Talend ETL to schedule this job and save the pdfs in a particular folder in my local.

But the problem is, while creation of pdf from the server it is missing some of the data and generating pdf!!! though complete set of data is available in the report??

I am using Jasperserver 6.3

Talend ETL community 6.01

and tjasperserverexec component to trigger pdf export.

Can any one pls suggest how to fix this words missing in the automated export of reports. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it is not possible to see how the broken pdf looks like (picture?) and how the report looks like (picture?) I think you won't find much help. This can have several reasons.

Comment: i have added line character and carriage return expressions and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

as it was missing the last line i just concatenated with \n\r for the column and it fixed the issue..